# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, typeerror

[image: I am getting below error while using routing]

```
         <Button
            variant="outlined"
            color="primary"
            //disabled={isDisabledSpec}
            onClick={this.handleSubmit}
            //onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
          >
```

This is the button tag, where handleSubmit being called.

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //const history = useHistory();
    this.props.history.push("/slider");
....}
```

This is handleSubmit function

Comment: `useHistory()` is a hook and can be used only inside functional components. If your component is not rendered by `Route`. Wrap it with `withRouter`, else convert it into functional component.

Comment: have you bind your `handleSubmit` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you wrap your component like this? if not wrap like this

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

 class Specification extends Component {(...)}
 export default withRouter(Specification);
```

and if you don't bind your function then use the arrow function

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push("/slider");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did, if I use 
`handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
const history = useHistory();
   this.props.history.push("/slider");
}`

it gives me


Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Comment: @tejesh as i see you are using class component, don't use hooks here...this.props.history.push() will work.

Comment: Yes, but with this I am getting
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Now it is working, I did some changes as you described

`import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
and
withRouter(Specification);`
Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the following steps to solve the problem

1. `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';`
2. `onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}`
3. ```
   handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.props.history.push("/slider");}
   ```
4. `export default withRouter(component_name);`